# Dell XPS 13 7390 Dual boot Window 10 and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 20.04, dell, windows-10

Dell XPS 13 7390 Dual boot Window 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 (latest as of 09/12/2020)
I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my Dell XPS 13 7390 (which runs Windows - 16 GB RAM- 516 GB memory) and I got stuck.

I’ve done all the following:

- Created space for Ubuntu by going to Disk Management (allocated 100 GB)
- Turned off Bitlocker
- Turned off Fastboot
- Disabled secure boot
- Enabled USB boot support
- Changed RAID to AHCI in BIOS

For preparing Ubuntu, I have a 8GB memory stick, Rufus, and Ubuntu 20.04.
I opened up Rufus. It recognized the stick. It recognized the Ubuntu ISO. I tried both GPT and MBR for Partition scheme.

All the videos and instructions I have seen and read say that when you reboot the laptop, you should now see the USB. I don’t! It’s just a black screen. I’m confused as to what I’m missing/doing wrong.

Comment: Dell Laptop XPS13 7390
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2438323 &
https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-13-Developers-edition-new-one-2019-won-t-boot-from-USB/td-p/7410750 &
https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/72936

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

I did the computer set-up correctly, but there was something wrong with the USB drive. I tested it on another computer and it wouldn't show up.

If the bootable USB works it should pop up as an option. If it doesn't, it might be corrupt like mine was so I learned I always need to test! Even if it seems like it works.